# Rewriting Angular.js app to do away with deferredBootstrapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to reverse engineer an application - and re-write it in a way to get rid of the deferredBootstrapper. I am running into module loading issues etc... am I invokling multiple modules correctly in the standard sense? The task at hand is simplify the application without the bootstrapper.

here is the initial deferredBootstrapper app.js code

```
app.init = function (callback) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        //for async test loading
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        } else {
            deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
                element: document,
                module: "ECP",
                injectorModules: ["ng", "ECP.services"],
                resolve: {
                    LOAD_CONFIG: [
                        "$http", "$q", "Account", "Layout", 
                            function($http, $q, Account, Layout) {
                                var configObj,
                                    deferred;

                                configObj = {
                                    account: null,
                                    layout: null
                                };

                                deferred = $q.defer();

                                Account.fetch()
                                    .then(function() {
                                        configObj.account = Account;
                                        return Layout.fetch();
                                    })
                                    .then(function() {
                                        configObj.layout = Layout;
                                        return deferred.resolve(configObj);
                                    });

                                return deferred.promise;
                            }
                    ]
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and I am trying to use this documentation as a base
http://beletsky.net/2013/11/using-angular-dot-js-with-require-dot-js.html

```
var app = angular.module("ECP", ["ng", "ECP.services"]);    
app.init = function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ["ECP"]);
    };

app.config(["$http", "$q", "Account", "Layout",
  function ($http, $q, Account, Layout) {
        var configObj,
            deferred;

        configObj = {
            account: null,
            layout: null
        };

        deferred = $q.defer();

        Account.fetch()
            .then(function() {
                configObj.account = Account;
                return Layout.fetch();
            })
            .then(function() {
                configObj.layout = Layout;
                return deferred.resolve(configObj);
            });

        return deferred.promise;          
  }
]);
```

but I am running into a cascade of errors. How do I restore the functionality without deferredBootstrapper

---

you mean like this

```
   Account.fetch()
            .then(function() {
                configObj.account = Account;
                return Layout.fetch();
            })
            .then(function() {
                configObj.layout = Layout;
                return deferred.resolve(configObj);
            })
            .finally(function(){
                return deferred.promise;  
            });
```

Comment: I would suggest you put the return in the `.finally()` in the fetch.

Comment: How to include the  injectorModules: ["ng", "ECP.services"]

Comment: Would it be like this? var app = angular.module("ECP", ["ng", "ECP.services"]);

Comment: Could you put up a plunkr or jsfiddle with the working code?

Comment: Well its part of an entire web application. I am finding it difficult to reverse engineer it - as I deal mostly with visualization frameworks and I didn't build the application which is spread over many files.

Comment: I've started to put it into a jsfiddle - but the essentials are not in place. 

Basic module invoke
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8577/

Broken version of the app in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8576/

Comment: I am trying to get this basic example going - but not been able to invoke require properly - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8581/

Comment: @TheOldCounty did the edited code of your question with the answer already solved your problem or you still need help? I mean, the snippet with the `.finnaly()`...

Comment: Sorry Kutyel, it was not enough. I lost the job